# is it possible to add ansible_ssh_common_args in inventory file

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

i want to jump/SSH Bastion Host using ProxyCommand of ansible_ssh_common_args.
ansible server:10.10.149.2
gateway/Bastion host:10.10.149.70
host to connect:10.32.32.190
So my aim is to connect 10.32.32.190 from 10.10.149.2 trough 10.10.149.70 (ssh tunneling)

ansible --version
ansible 2.1.0.0

my inventory:

```
[local]
10.10.149.2

[Private]
10.32.32.190

[Private:vars]
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q root@10.10.149.70"'
```

pingtest.yml:

```
---
- hosts: Private
  tasks:
- name: test connection
  ping:
  register: ping1
- debug: var=ping1
```

Issue facing:

```
 fatal: [10.32.32.190]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.", "unreachable": true}
```

So i doubt ansible_ssh_common_args support in inventory file.i do not want to use the ssh.config file.

Logs:

```
   [root@mavosdsc ansible]# ansible-playbook -i inventory pingtest.yml -e "user=root" --ask-pass -vvvv
   Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
   SSH password: 
   Loaded callback default of type stdout, v2.0

   PLAYBOOK: pingtest.yml *********************************************************
   1 plays in pingtest.yml

   PLAY [Private] *****************************************************************

   TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
   <10.32.32.190> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
   <10.32.32.190> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d12 ssh -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r 10.32.32.190 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1469788026.71-124524328003439 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1469788026.71-124524328003439="` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1469788026.71-124524328003439 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
   fatal: [10.32.32.190]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.", "unreachable": true}
   to retry, use: --limit @pingtest.retry

   PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
   10.32.32.190               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

Comment: Please check `-vvvv` output for specific ssh error. `ansible_ssh_common_args` should work fine in inventory. I use it in ./group_vars/all.yml without problems.

Comment: TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
<10.32.32.183> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None

Comment: There is a typo in `[Private.vars]` it should be `Private:vars`

Comment: [Private]
10.32.32.190                                                                              [Private:vars]
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q root@10.10.149.70"' my mistake and changed it .now also same thing. i doubt the  <10.32.32.190> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None

Comment: You've also changed `=` to `:` in assigment – this is not correct, revert to `=`.

Comment: thanks its working fine now.even all the changes it did not work.so created a new inventory file with all these changes and finally worked.

Comment: can the value be referenced inside of playbooks like so "{{ ansible_ssh_common_args }}" ?

Answer (score 24):

The problem is here:
`ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q root@10.10.149.70"'`

Replace ":" by "=" and write like this:
`ansible_ssh_common_args='-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q root@10.10.149.70"'`

To help others, keep in mind that your inventory file is a '.ini' file.
'.ini' files e.g `ansible.cfg`, use '=' to assign variables, as 'yaml' files use ':'.